# Random Percentage bar javascript that changes every 30 minutes

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, and I just finished some videos on Youtube about it. So anyways I have a percentage bar, what I want to do with it is update it every 30 minutes randomly and I don't know how to figure it out.

```js
var x = [0, 106, 69, 33, 1119, 1474, 585, 1062, 714, 1038, 1241, 1091, 218, 403, 132, 1302, 1027, 1108, 385, 317, 564, 399, 475, 621, 109, 602, 217, 893, 581, 274, 321, 435, 741, 662, 846, 277, 1, 776, 103, 336, 856, 830, 198, 843, 187, 10, 409, 848, 583, 885, 402, 200, 929, 816, 454, 424, 587, 72, 488, 269, 238, 958, 772, 185, 959, 685, 966, 889, 403, 629, 126, 166, 368, 391, 492, 142, 710, 503, 850, 996, 363, 588, 633, 293, 936, 960, 268, 491, 514, 41, 833, 948, 582, 709, 239, 341, 182, 191, 48, 32, 908, 540, 144, 110, 632, 141, 729, 522, 859, 954, 184, 286, 586, 845, 779, 866, 573, 74, 924, 786, 911, 768, 143, 157, 676, 446, 70, 120, 518, 490, 783, 222, 389, 225, 34, 450, 910, 873, 725, 324, 311, 963, 177, 558, 876, 65, 903, 2, 271, 305, 234, 146, 826, 92, 80, 533, 96, 136, 122, 969, 314, 323, 722, 457, 379, 838, 909, 809, 626, 704, 767, 90, 683, 447, 281, 357, 438, 825, 366, 991, 914, 962, 794, 61, 414, 670, 60, 349, 874, 753, 232, 527, 3, 27, 721, 350, 374, 917, 218];
for (let i = 1; i <= 181; i++) {
  const d = new Date();
  var date = d.getUTCDate();
  var day = d.getUTCDay() + 1;
  var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
  var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  var hour = d.getUTCHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  if (min < 30) {
    min = 1;
  } else {
    min = 2;
  }
  var xx = day + year * month * date;
  xx = Math.pow(xx, hour * min);
  xx = xx * x[i];
  if (i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 2 || i == 114 || i == 73 || i == 41 || i == 4 || i == 92 || i == 134 || i == 10 || i == 78 || i == 66) {
    xx = xx % 27;
    xx += 65;
  } else {
    xx = xx % 83;
    xx += 8;
  }
  const as = "percent-bar-" + i;
  const asd = "percent-txt-" + i;
  var percentTxt = document.getElementById("percent-txt-" + i);
  var bar = document.getElementById("percent-bar-" + i);
  const bartext = document.getElementById("card-title" + i);
  percentTxt.innerHTML = xx + "%";
  $("#percent-bar-" + i).attr("aria-valuenow", xx).css("width", xx + "%");
  if (xx < 30) {
    bar.classList.add("red");
  } else if (xx > 70) {
    bar.classList.add("green");
  } else {
    bar.classList.add("yellow");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="percent">
  <p id="percent-txt-1" style="z-index: 15"> 46 %</p>
  <div id="percent-bar-1" class="percent-bar yellow" role="progressbar" aria - valuemin="0" aria - valuemax="100" aria - valuenow="46" style="width: 46%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about `setInterval(function() { randomizeBarValue() }, 1000 * 60 * 30)`; It randomize the progressbar's value every `1000 * 60 * 30` milliseconds (30 minutes)

Comment: You're using both Jquery and native JS DOM manipulation. You should stick with one or the other.

Comment: where i could put that code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `date/time` to update it in after 30 minutes a basic `setInterval` will work. Also you don't need 3 elements for making a progress bar a signle `div` should enough.

```js
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar')

setInterval(() => {
  let random = Math.random() * 100

  progressBar.style.setProperty('--progress', random.toFixed(2) + '%')
  progressBar.setAttribute('data-progress', random.toFixed(2) + '%')
}, 1000) // Change 1000 to 30 * 60000 for changing after 30 minutes.
```

```css
@import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css';

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.progress-bar {
  --progress: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  max-width: 450px;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

.progress-bar::before {
  content: attr(data-progress);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.progress-bar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: var(--progress);
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 250ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar" data-progress="0%"></div>
```